# Let $G$ be a group such that for all $x,y\in G,(xy)^3=x^3y^3$ and $(xy)^8=x^8y^8$. Prove that $G$ is Abelian or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I tried to prove it like $(xy)^3=xyxyxy=x^3y^3 $ which implies

$$ x^{-1}/x^3y^3=xyxyxy$$

$$x^2y^3=yxyxy/y^{-1}$$

$$ x^2y^2=yxyx $$

and I get $x^2y^2=(yx)^2$.

But I dont know how to prove that $(xy)^3=x^3y^3$

Comment: Why do you want to prove the equality that is given?

Comment: So I’m practicing for the test and I found this assignment that I got stuck on.
If You can help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Knowing that $(xy)^3 = x^3y^3$ and $(xy)^8 = x^8y^8$, you need to prove that $xy = yx$. Trying to prove the given condition does not make sense.

Comment: $\gcd(9-3,64-8) = \gcd(6,46)=2$, so all groups satisfying $(xy)^3 = x^3y^3$ and $(xy)^8 = x^8y^8$ [are abelian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284226/groups-for-which-the-n-power-map-is-a-homomorphism).

Comment: You don’t need “to prove $(xy)^3 =x^3y^3$. You are **assuming** that this condition holds for this particular group $G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, but that is a rather heavy-handed proof (The OP, and most of us, don't know what a Levi system is...)

Comment: @IgorRivin: To be perfectly honest, I did not really intend it to be useful to the OP, given the quality of the post... But I figured some might find the more general result interesting.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin And you were right! But the MO answer must contain the elementary trick, I think - it is just difficult to isolate it...

Comment: @IgorRivin: It’s too deeply hidden, I think. It essentially comes down to the properties of the Levi system; the elementary trick shows that if $G$ is $n$-abelian, then it satisfies $(ab)^{n-1}=b^{n-1}a^{n-1}$ (which is why $n$-abelian holds if and only if $(1-n)$-abelian holds, a property of Levi systems). This also implies that $n-1$st powers commute with $n$th powers. The argument below uses this to conclude that $8$th powers are central, and then that squares are central.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, makes sense. Of course, the first trick is the first thing one tries, but then it gets a bit non-scientific :)

Comment: Thank you all so much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prove commutativity. (The comments
reveal that a more general result was proved in 2017.)  The proof is for cancellative semigroups.

$$\ (xy)^3=x^3y^3\tag{A}$$
$$\ (xy)^8=x^8y^8\tag{B}$$

Using cancellation on (A), $(yx)^2=x^2y^2 \tag 1$

Therefore, $x^2y^3x=(yx)^3=y^3x^3$ so that $x^2y^3=y^3x^2\tag 2$

Using cancellation on (B), $(yx)^7=x^7y^7 \tag 3$

Therefore, $x^7y^8x=(yx)^8=y^8x^8$ so that $x^7y^8=y^8x^7\tag 4$

Apply (2) to (4) to obtain $xy^8x^6=y^8x^7$ and cancel to get
$xy^8=y^8x \tag 5$

From $y^6x^2y^2=x^2y^8=y^8x^2,$ we obtain

$x^2y^2=y^2x^2 \tag 6$

Apply (6) to (2) to obtain the powerful identity
$x^2y=yx^2 \tag 7$
Commutativity now follows by cancellation on

$$x^3y^3=(xy)^3=x(xy)^2y=x^2yxy^2.$$

Comment: Thank You for this. :)